# using multiple integration tools on hdfs

Tags: frameworks, hdfs, batch-processing, data-ingestion, data-lake

I am working on a small project. The aim of the project is to use framework ingestion tools to ingest data in to a data lake.

-I will be ingesting data in batches.
-The data formats will be RDBMS, csv files and flat files.

I've done my research on the ingestion tools to use and I have found plenty like: Sqoop, Flume, Gobblin, Kafka etc.

My question is: What ingestion tools or approaches do you recommend for this small project? (keep in mind I'll be using HDFS as my lake)

Comment: after 2months, may i know which tool you used?

Comment: Apache sqoop for RDBMS and apache flume for streaming twitter logs